# Replacement for "su user_with_sudo; sudo -s" for user without sudo-rights?

Tags: sudo, su, sudoers

Let's say I have two user accounts:

- user (without any sudo permissions)
- user_with_sudo (with all sudo permissions)

Now, I'm logged in as `user` but want to do something as `root`, e.g. switch to a full root Bash. `sudo -s` won't work because I'm not a sudoer.

So, I first have to switch to a sudoer user:

```
su user_with_sudo
```

And enter the password.

Now I'm logged in as `user_with_sudo` and I'm able to call `sudo -s` but I have to enter the same password again, which is a little bit annoying.

Is there a command, which switches to a sudoer-user and runs a command as `root` with only typing the password once? Basically, is there an one-command replacement for:

```
su user_with_sudo
(enter password)
sudo -s
(enter same password again)
```

Comment: What's the point of this configuration? If you're giving all these people the password for `user_with_sudo`, why not just give them the root password?

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of the sudo command you can edit the /etc/sudoers file to allow this

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43135/allowing-a-user-to-use-sudo-without-a-password

Comment: This would add sudo rights to "user", which I wanted to prevent.
The user account "user" is meant as a shared account for many people, they shouldn't be allowed to alter the system.
Another option would be to request an other password when calling sudo, but I'm just wondering if it's possible to call "sudo as user_with_sudo" with one command instead of su & sudo.

Comment: @Bernhard I think he's suggesting that you turn off the password requirement for `user_with_sudo`. So everyone else has to enter the password to become that user, but they don't have to enter the password again to become root.